# How do I initialize an array with Label objects in visual basic.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

http://pastebin.com/3A4P61Gt The code in question is specifically at line 143. Whenever I try to access a label in the array like so Dicelbls(0).Text I get a null reference error. Obviously I am not declaring the array right, any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: Write a small code to debug/test arrays of label.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the problem is at line 143:

```
Dim Dicelbls As Label() = {lblP1Die0, lblP1Die1, lblP1Die2, lblP2Die0, lblP2Die1, lblP2Die2, lblP1Score, lblP2Score}
```

Specifically, at the point in the object initialization process when this code runs, the references behind those Label variables are still null/Nothing.  So you're putting references to Nothing into your array.

To fix the code, move the initialization to the Form_Load event instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add initialization in Form_Load event.

```
Dim Dicelbls As Label()

Private Sub Form1_Load(..)
  Dicelbls= new Label() {lblP1Die0, lblP1Die1, lblP1Die2, lblP2Die0, lblP2Die1, lblP2Die2, lblP1Score, lblP2Score}
....
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the array correctly, but in the wrong place.  Leave the variable declaration where it is, and move the assignment to somewhere after the form is created.

```
Class frmMain

    Dim Dicelbls As Label()

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dicelbls = {lblP1Die0, lblP1Die1, lblP1Die2, lblP2Die0, lblP2Die1, lblP2Die2, lblP1Score, lblP2Score}
    End Sub

    ...

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Dim Dicelbls(8) As Label
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dicelbls = {lblP1Die0, lblP1Die1, lblP1Die2, lblP2Die0, lblP2Die1, lblP2Die2, lblP1Score, lblP2Score}
End Sub
```